# Camera button reassign function

Tags: buttons

So my power button broke on my droid 1 (yes old phone). Until I can get a new phone soon, I need a better way to lock and unlock my screen. Sliding up and down the keyboard slows down everything.

Is there an app or a way that lets me re-assign my physical camera button to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. The first one coming to mind (forgive me, it looks like this is one of my standard answers here meanwhile) is [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), the most complete automation tool for Android. It lets you define actions based on events; so for your case, you could let the event *Hardware -> Camera button pressed* trigger the action "Display off".

You want to turn it on again the same way -- so simply make it two "profiles", and combine two events: *"Camera button pressed" & "State -> Display: On"* (with the "task" to turn the display off), and with "Display: Off" the other way round.

Remark: There's a 7 day trial version available on the developers website, so you don't need to buy Tasker straight away without being able to test it. As soon as you've got everything configured, export your configuration. So if after those 7 days you still cannot decide whether to buy, simply uninstall *Tasker*, install it again, and import your configuration. Before you hit me: That's what the developer himself wrote, so nothing illegal.

Comment: You are very welcome -- glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Camera Touch-Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sbg.camera).

> **Description**
>
> Solution for touch phones that did not have hardware camera button..
>
> Making shots on touch phone without touches
>
> Just use hardware buttons "Volume Up" or headset..
>
> Use "Volume Down" hardware button for exit from application..

Comment: This isn't what I was asking. I was asking for an app that would let me reassign my hardware camera button to be a lock/unlock button. I solved it before, and not only that this was on an old device i had in 2012